# Swapping raster extents, left/right and top/bottom extents need to be reversed

Tags: raster, arcmap, extents

I have a raster layer that was delivered with the extent boundaries (Latitude and Longitude) reversed and no spatial reference; resulting in an improperly oriented and georeferenced image:

```
Top: -120.5  
Left: 34.0 
Right: 34.2 
Bottom: -120.6
```

What I need is:

```
Top: 34.2 
Left: -120.6 
Right: -120.5 
Bottom: 34.0
```

My only workaround was using the rotate and flip tools to orient the image properly, but this still doesn't remedy the georeferenceing issue. I redefined the image into the proper spatial reference, but because of the extents, it still draws in the wrong location. I suspect there is a simple way to redefine the extents? Or is there a way to scrap all the erroneous parameters and input the correct ones?

Comment: You have to update the georeferencing. There's a toolbar for that. Then you can set the coordinate system/spatial reference to whatever geographic one it is.